# ipad while scrolling it immediately goes to link if touched

Tags: ios

How would you stop Safari on iPad immediately clicking the link when user tries to scroll up and down the page?

What's the jquery to stop this?

Comment: Scrolling does not usually trigger a touch event on iOS. Do you have a code sample that illustrates the issue?

Comment: until the `UIScrollView` decelerates to still state, it won't send any action towards its subviews. so, the first tap only stops the scrolling but that touch won't be sent to the subviews.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an iOS issue.  This sounds like a HTML5 issue.